# Can't write image in air for android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

This code works great in a desktop air application but doesn't work at all in android. is this not possible yet in air for android? here's my code.

```
    var theImage:BitmapData = new BitmapData(imageArea.width,imageArea.height);
    theImage.draw(imageArea);
    var jpgStream:ByteArray = theEncoder.encode(theImage);
    var fileName:String = "pf_" + int(Math.random() * 10000) + ".jpg";
    while(File.userDirectory.resolvePath("DCIM/Camera/" + fileName).exists)
        fileName = "pf_" + int(Math.random() * 10000) + ".jpg";
    trace(fileName);
    var fl:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath("DCIM/Camera/" + fileName);
    var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
    trace(fl.url);
    try{
            fs.open(fl,FileMode.WRITE);
            fs.writeBytes(jpgStream);
            fs.close();
    }catch(e:Error){
            trace(e.message);
    }
```

I get this trace on the fl.url 
    file:///mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/pf_2570.jpg

image area is a flex group with several displayed children. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try to debug your code, but what you are doing should work. It is certainly possible to write to files with AIR on Android. Are you sure jpgStream has data?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the android permission to write content on SD card? ( or external storage )

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```